# fileupload's upload button works different in IE and Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

For those who worked with bootstrap, knows it does not support input type = file, so I hide the asp:fileupload using jQuery (after document ready), and have  and  for the solution (as you can see from the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#columnSelect').change(function ()
        {
            getImportColumnOrder();
        });

        // change file upload style similiar to bootstrap style
        //$('#uploader').hide();
        $('#uploader').change(function ()
        {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var file = val.split(/[\\/]/);
            $('#file').val(file[file.length - 1]);

        });

    });

    function getImportColumnOrder()
    {
        var order = '';
        $('#selectOrer').val('');

        $('select', $('#MappingTable')).each(function ()
        {
            order += $(this).prop('selectedIndex') + ',';
        });

        $('#selectOrder').val(order.substr(0, order.length - 1));

    }


</script>
<div class="span12">

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_DBTableList" runat="server" CssClass="combobox" Style="display: inline">

                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>

                    <asp:ListItem Value="Import_Test">Import_Test</asp:ListItem>

                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:FileUpload ID="uploader" runat="server" CssClass="btn" />

                <div class="input-append" style="display: inline;">
                    <input id="file" class="input-medium" type="text" />
                    <a class="btn" onclick="$('input[id=uploader]').click();">Select File</a>
                </div>

                <p />

                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_uplaod" runat="server" OnClick="doUpload" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn" />
                </div>

                <p />

                <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>

                <p />

                <asp:Label ID="data" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC"></asp:Label>

                <p />

                <asp:Button ID="btn_import" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="doImport" OnClientClick="getImportColumnOrder();return true;" Visible="false" CssClass="btn btn-success" />

            </div>
```

Steps are click on the "Select File", a file chooser popped up for file selection. After double clicked a file, the file location gets displayed in , and also the asp fileupload control.

In Chrome and FF, when I clicked btn_uplaod (button), it runs as supposed. In IE, it will clear the fileupload's content and does nothing (a client side action) and will not do any postback.

If this is a program problem, then maybe Chrome and FF will not run correctly. I'm suspecting is there anything that I need to add to make IE run as suppose to?

image after click upload (IE), (Browse link is cleared)
[image]

image after click upload (Chrome), (Run as supposed to)
[image]

thanks!

I've made a simple version for those of you who wants to try on Visual studio:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="postback_problem.aspx.cs" Inherits="postback_problem" %> <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server"> <title></title> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> <body> <form id="form1" runat="server"> <div> <asp:FileUpload ID="uploader" runat="server" CssClass="btn" /> <div> <input id="file" class="input-medium" type="text" /> <a onclick="$('input[id=uploader]').click();">Select File</a> </div> <p /> <div> <asp:Button ID="btn_uplaod" runat="server" OnClick="doUpload" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn" /> </div> <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server"></asp:Label> </div> </form> </body> </html>
```

and

```
 using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; public partial class postback_problem : System.Web.UI.Page { protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { } protected void doUpload(object sender, EventArgs e) { result.Text = "no problem!"; } }
```

Comment: does anyone has an answer to this?